# How to clear the textfield input in child class when click the reset button in parent class

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

[Here is structure of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Io0.jpg)

in the Parent class, i have create 2 floating buttons which are Reset and Add item. But now, the reset button when i click on it, the input in textfield which is in the child widget is not be cleared.

Here is my parent class coding part,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/compare_item.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/dialog_popup.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/item_model.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'shopping_list.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class ComparisonScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<int> item;

  ComparisonScreen({super.key,required this.item});

  @override
  State<ComparisonScreen> createState() => _ComparisonScreenState();
}

class _ComparisonScreenState extends State<ComparisonScreen> {

  List<int> _item = <int>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _item = widget.item;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  int itemNum = 2;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });

    if (index == 0) {
      Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ShoppingListScreen()),
      );
    }
  }

  List item =[
    [1,false],
    [2,false],
  ];


  void checkBoxChanged(bool? value, int index){
    setState(() {
      item[index][1] =!item[index][1];
    });
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
      return DialogPopUp();
    },);
  }

  void addItem(){
    setState(() {
     if( itemNum+1 < 5){
       item.add([itemNum+1,false]);
       itemNum = itemNum+1;
     }
    });
  }

  void reset(){
    setState(() {
      item[0][1] =false;
      item[1][1] =false;
      while(itemNum > 2){
        item.removeAt(itemNum-1);
        itemNum= itemNum-1;
      }
    });
  }

  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Comparison',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: headAndTailBG,
        foregroundColor: kDarkGreen,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      label: const Text(
                        'Reset',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: redText,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: kLigthRed,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.refresh,
                        size: 24.0,
                        color: redText,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("Reset");
                        reset();
                        _controller.clear();
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      label: const Text(
                        'Add Item',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: kDarkBlue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: kLigthBlue,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.add_circle_outline,
                        size: 24.0,
                        color: kDarkBlue,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        addItem();
                        print("Add Item");
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],

          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
              itemCount: item.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CompareItem(
                  itemNum: item[index][0],
                  addCart: item[index][1],
                  onChanged: (value) => checkBoxChanged(value, index),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.balance),
            label: 'Comparison',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
            label: 'Shopping List',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: kDarkGreen,
        backgroundColor: headAndTailBG,
        unselectedFontSize: 15,
        selectedFontSize: 20,
        selectedIconTheme:
        const IconThemeData(color: kDarkGreen, size: 28),
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my child class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list/comparison_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'base_card.dart';
import 'item_model.dart';

class CompareItem extends StatefulWidget {

  CompareItem({
    required this.itemNum, required this.addCart, required this.onChanged
  });

  final int itemNum;
  final bool addCart;
  Function(bool?)? onChanged;

  @override
  CompareItemState createState() => CompareItemState();


}
class CompareItemState extends State<CompareItem> {

  List<int> item = List<int>.filled(3, 0);

  final sizeController = TextEditingController();
  final qtyController = TextEditingController();
  final priceController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> myItem1 = Provider.of<ItemModel>(context).item1;
    List<int> myItem2 = Provider.of<ItemModel>(context).item2;
    List<int> myItem3 = Provider.of<ItemModel>(context).item3;
    List<int> myItem4 = Provider.of<ItemModel>(context).item4;
    return Container(

      child: Column(children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 20,top: 20),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Item "+ widget.itemNum.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: kLightGrey),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Add to cart",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: kDarkGreen),
                    ),
                    Checkbox(value: widget.addCart, onChanged: widget.onChanged, activeColor: kDarkGreen,)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15,),
          child: BaseCard(
            theColor: backgroundButton,
            theChild: Container(
              width: 600.0,
              height: 150.0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 7),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: BaseCard(
                            theColor: kDarkGrey,
                            theChild: Container(
                              width: 80.0,
                              height: 40.0,
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Size",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: kWhite,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: BaseCard(
                            theColor: kDarkGrey,
                            theChild: Container(
                              width: 80.0,
                              height: 40.0,
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Qty",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: kWhite,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: BaseCard(
                            theColor: kDarkGrey,
                            theChild: Container(
                              width: 80.0,
                              height: 40.0,
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Price",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: kWhite,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(

                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: BaseCard(
                            theColor: kLightGreen,
                            theChild: Container(
                              width: 100.0,
                              height: 80.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: sizeController,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    item[0] = int.tryParse(value) ?? 0;
                                    if (widget.itemNum == 1 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem1(item);
                                    }else if (widget.itemNum == 2 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem2(item);
                                    }else if (widget.itemNum == 3 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem3(item);
                                    }else{
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem4(item);
                                    }

                                  },
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: kWhite),
                                    ),
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: kWhite,
                                  ),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: kDarkGreen,
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                                  ], // Only numbers can be entered
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: BaseCard(
                            theColor: kLightGreen,
                            theChild: Container(
                              width: 100.0,
                              height: 80.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: qtyController,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    item[1] = int.tryParse(value) ?? 0;
                                    if (widget.itemNum == 1 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem1(item);
                                    }else if (widget.itemNum == 2 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem2(item);
                                    }else if (widget.itemNum == 3 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem3(item);
                                    }else{
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem4(item);
                                    }
                                  },
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: kWhite),
                                    ),
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: kWhite,
                                  ),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: kDarkGreen,
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                                  ], // Only numbers can be entered
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: BaseCard(
                            theColor: kLightGreen,
                            theChild: Container(
                              width: 100.0,
                              height: 80.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: priceController,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    item[2] = int.tryParse(value) ?? 0;
                                    if (widget.itemNum == 1 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem1(item);
                                    }else if (widget.itemNum == 2 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem2(item);
                                    }else if (widget.itemNum == 3 ){
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem3(item);
                                    }else{
                                      Provider.of<ItemModel>(context, listen: false).updateMyItem4(item);
                                    }
                                  },
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: kWhite),
                                    ),
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: kWhite,
                                  ),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: kDarkGreen,
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(4),
                                  ], // Only numbers can be entered
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            theOnTapFunc: () {
              print('pressed');
              // print(item);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to clear all input textfield by i click the reset button

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

Inside your Parent class :

```
class _ComparisonScreenState extends State<ComparisonScreen> {
...
final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
                    FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      label: const Text(
                        'Reset',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: redText,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: kLigthRed,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.refresh,
                        size: 24.0,
                        color: redText,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("Reset");
                        reset();
                        _controller.clear();

                        /// The Code that will Clear fields
                        formKey.currentState!.reset();
                      },
                    ),
      ...
      ...
      ...
           Expanded(
            child: Form(
              key: formKey, 
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                itemCount: item.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   return CompareItem(
                    itemNum: item[index][0],
                    addCart: item[index][1],
                    onChanged: (value) => checkBoxChanged(value, index),
                   );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ...
      ...

    );
  }
...
}
```